# PostgreSQL - Query a single column table containing 5 element array per row to return array split into 5 columns per row

Tags: sql, arrays, postgresql, unnest

I need to take the contents of this single column table, containing a 5 element array per row:

```
Col1
----
{a,b,c,d,e}
{f,g,h,i,j}
{a,f,r,y,t}
...
```

and achieve this:

```
colA | ColB | ColC | ColD | ColE
  a  |   b  |  c   |  d   |  e
  f  |   g  |  h   |  i   |  j
  a  |   f  |  r   |  y   |  t
```

I have tried using unnest(string_to_array):

```
SELECT unnest(string_to_array('a,b,c,d,e', ',')) AS splitvals
```

but end up with

```
splitvals
a
b
c
d
e
```

But I need each array element split into a separate column without having to resort to split_part(). In other contexts I may have a 7 element array per row so it would be nice to have a more 'generic' query to achieve it for any array size, without just adding split_part() for each additional element.

Any ideas please?

---

Found answer using:

```
    SELECT NULLIF(p[1],'') AS Col1,
       NULLIF(p[2],'') AS Col2,
       NULLIF(p[3],'') AS Col3,
       NULLIF(p[4],'') AS Col4,
       NULLIF(p[5],'') AS Col5
FROM (
  SELECT string_to_array('a,b,c,d,e', ',') AS p
  ) x
```

Comment: You cannot have a generic "query", because a SQL query has a single set of columns, defined in advance.  The number of columns can only vary if you use dynamic SQL.

Comment: Yes, I should have been more explicit and said I didn't want an extra split_part() function per additional array element present

Comment: Maybe you can custom the answer of this question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57956669/how-can-i-transform-a-column-containing-some-strings-into-multi-columns-using-po . And maybe it is a duplicate though...

Comment: @ChrisThomas What's the data type, an array or text-based? Assuming array, you can just do `SELECT col1[1], col1[2], col1[3], ...`; if string then split the string first then use array indexing as above to get the columns.

Comment: Thanks @Jaisus. A combination of both yours and 404's recommendations helped me solve it!

Comment: Thanks @404. A combination of both yours and Jai's recommendations helped me solve it!